# Reledmac: Customize familiar notes mark

Tags: macros, footnotes, reledmac

I would like to make a the footnote mark smaller, and, in the familiar footnotes, distance the text from the mark. I have tried the `\thefootnoteA` macro (reledmac manual 6.5.2), but I don't know how to figure it out. Do you have any suggestions?
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\parindentX
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{\Afootnote{A critical note}}
\edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{An other critical note}}
 dolor sit amet. Fusce\footnoteA{A Familiar note (very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long)} sed dolor libero. Aenean\footnote{A regular note (very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long)} rutrum vestibulum lacus ut pretium. Fusce et auctor lectus. Ut et commodo quam, quis gravida orci. Nullam at risus elementum, suscipit enim a, pellentesque mi
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to change for the reledmac footnote of the `A` series   (`\footnoteA`), despite the fact that in your example, you use also standard LaTeX footnote (`\footnote`)

You must redefine

- `\bodyfootmarkA` to get the footnote mark smaller in the body. Just take the standard definition, and add a font size command.
- `footfootmarkA` to add space after footnote mark in the footnote. Just take the standard definition, and add a `\hspace` command.

As these commands use `@` you must wrap your redefinition by `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\parindentX
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bodyfootmarkA}{%
  \hbox{%
      \textsuperscript{%
        \tiny%\Tiny, or other little size
        \normalfont\@nameuse{@thefnmarkA}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{%
  \textsuperscript{\@nameuse{@thefnmarkA}}%
  \nobreak%Eventually, prevent break
  \hspace{1em}%1em, but you can decide your size
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{\Afootnote{A critical note}}
\edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{An other critical note}}
 dolor sit amet. Fusce\footnoteA{A Familiar note (very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long)} sed dolor libero. Aenean\footnote{A regular note (very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long)} rutrum vestibulum lacus ut pretium. Fusce et auctor lectus. Ut et commodo quam, quis gravida orci. Nullam at risus elementum, suscipit enim a, pellentesque mi
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your way, or the distance between the text and the mark, but here's a way I got a smaller footnote mark which at least, hopefully, answers part of your question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\tiny{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text with a smaller footnote mark\footnote{The footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

You can of course replace the `\tiny` command with other sizes e.g. `\Huge` etc..

Comment: that can't work with reledmac footnote, which are specific.